# Python - same else code for nested ifs

Tags: python, django

In Django, the canonical way of processing forms is:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SomeForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        use the form data
```

I want to execute the same code whether there was no POST or the form was invalid - it's a few lines of code, so I'm wondering if there is a nicer way of doing this than having two duplicate else blocks (one for the inner if and one for the outer)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very concise way that does not require a separate function, and doesn't repeat conditions:

```
form = SomeForm(request.POST) if request.method == 'POST' else None

if form and form.is_valid():
    # do your valid-submission stuff
else:
    # do your invalid-submission stuff
```

Answer (score 6):

Use a separate function:

```
if request.method != 'POST':
    return do_something_function_for_invalid(request)

form = SomeForm(request.POST)
if not form.is_valid():
    return do_something_function_for_invalid(request)

# do something
```

and then define `do_something_function_for_invalid()` as:

```
def do_something_function_for_invalid(request):
    # do something

    return response
```

Alternatively, use exception handling:

```
try:
    if request.method != 'POST':
        raise ValueError('invalid form')

    form = SomeForm(request.POST)
    if not form.is_valid():
        raise ValueError('not a POST request')

     # do something
except ValueError as ve:
    # handle ve exception, ve.args[0] is the error message
```

Comment: You might even define `do_something_function` locally and don't worry about passing arguments.

Comment: @freakish: there is a (very small) cost when you do that; just define the function outside the view function and pass in arguments instead.

Comment: Here you have two duplicate else blocks that is what  the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: @furins: Reduced to less nesting, removing the `else` statements.

Comment: There's a simpler way of doing this, as I've demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: @Amber: This is now reasonably simpler too; I'd say all three approaches (function, exception and flag variable) are valid.

Comment: I also like some of the suggestions in this answer, and may use them in similar situations. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As simple as

```
if (request.method != 'POST') or (not SomeForm(request.POST).is_valid()):
   do something
```

Comment: -1: keeping reference to `SomeForm` object is probably crucial.

Comment: Please let the OP say that, he may just require this code in order to output a message

Comment: @furins You are suggesting that OP creates form but he's not using it anywhere neither in *if* nor *else* block? He doesn't have state it, it is obvious.

Comment: It's not stated so the only one who knows that is the OP. It may be a honeypot-like code to check if fake requests are provided to a given url